# leading NA is causing "POSIXct" "POSIXt" to be coereced to type integer

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I have column of dates and a grouping column. I am creating a next.date and preivous.date based on the groups - with the following code.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dates <- ymd(c("2014-01-23","2014-01-28","2014-02-22","2014-05-30","2014-07-09","2014-09-08","2014-10-19","2014-11-25","2014-12-05","2014-12-13"))
group <- c("A","B","A","A","B","C","C","A","B","C")

data <- data.table(dates,group)
data <- data[order(dates)]

#Create previous and next dates
#Previous is coerced to type integer

data <- data[, next.date     := c(dates[-1], NA),by = .(group)]
data <- data[, previous.date := c(NA,dates[-.N]),by = .(group)]
```

With a leading NA as in previous.date - the type is coerced to integer. Question: Is it possible to stop this. I can do this with this.

```
data <- data[, previous.date := ymd(c(NA,dates[-.N])),by = .(group)]
```

This is not optimal on large data

Comment: First of all, don't use `lubridate::ymd`, instead use `data.table::as.IDate`. Second of all, please don't do `data <- data` when assigning by reference.  Third of all, this is probably happening because you are assigning `NA` at the beginning of each group which is an integer on C level (IIRC) and then the rest of the group also coereced accordingly as you can't have multiple data classes in the same column. Finally, `data.table` has a function for this. Just do `data[, prev := shift(dates), by = group]` (don't do `data <- data` !!!). P.S. - Also see `?setorder`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about shift - works perfect. Thanks for the assignment info - i had been doing with rmarkdown and assign by reference didn't work in earlier version of data.table.

Comment: The "previous.date" is not, actually, coerced nor to integer (POSIXct is a double) -- it loses its "class" attribute since `c(NA, <POSIXct>)` uses the default `c` method. On the other hand `c(<POSIXct>, NA)` dispatches on `c.POSIXct`.